# How to make Rails migration conditional on current RAILS_ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

How do you make a Rails migration conditional on the current RAILS_ENV?

Specifically, I want to:

1. Check a migration into head-of-master
2. Execute the migration only on our Staging instance

Doing this will allow us to perform database updates - via migrations - which we only want in our Staging environment. An example would be activating a feature for a specific account or class of accounts for testing purposes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `Rails.env.production?` / `Rails.env.<custom-env>?` in your up / down class methods in the Migration.

Comment: Thank you! I should have thought of this myself. Appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Not working with Rails 3.2.13. Getting `undefined local variable or method Rails`